# Angular 6 Service adding new instance from inside the method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a service that looks like this:

```
export class myService {

  view1 = new Viewer();

  constructor() { }


  viewit(targetId, param2, param3) {

    this.view1.initialize(document.getElementById(targetId));

    this.view1.load(param2, param3).then(pco => {
      // do stuff
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
```

then from the component I call it:

```
this.myService.viewit('targetId', 'param2 here', 'param3 here');
```

How can I pass or define the  `view1 = new Viewer();` to whatever name I need it without having to pre-define it in the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about the following :

in your service :

```
export class myService {

  constructor() { }


  viewit(targetId, param2, param3, view: Viewer) {

    view.initialize(document.getElementById(targetId));

    view.load(param2, param3).then(pco => {
      // do stuff
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
```

and match it in your component :

const view = new Viewer()

```
this.myService.viewit('targetId', 'param2 here', 'param3 here', view);
```